# Rails 3 Escape BBCode-parsed HTML Only Within Pre+Code Tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, bbcode

I'm trying to implement a markup system in my Rails application using the [bb-ruby](https://github.com/cpjolicoeur/bb-ruby) gem. Currently I'm working on something similar to how Stackoverflow handles it's code markdown and I ran into some difficulty.

Essentially I want the user-entered text:

> [code]<h1>Headline</h1>[/code]

To spit out the code in plain-text, perhaps in a pre and code tag block. Passing that string of text to my code parser will wrap the code in a pre and code block but the HTML also gets rendered. I pass the string to my code parser like so:

```
sanitize(text.bbcode_to_html(formats, false).html_safe)
```

Of course, if I remove the .html_safe helper from the call my view will spit out:

> <pre><code><br /> <h1>Hello World</h1><br /> </code></pre>

Obviously that's not the desired result. **So my question is, how can I accomplish plain-text code only within the pre + code tags while maintaining the html_safe helper method?**

Comment: I never said it was markdown - by "stackoverflow-like" I meant in the sense that you're taking plain text and parsing that into HTML. I probably could have gave a better example but none came to mind. This is definitely more of a Rails/HTML problem than a markup/markdown problem, however. Updated for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but you can try using the `strip_tags` after the `bbcode_to_html` one.